# Integer/Round problem in getting the sum of 3 different numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, numbers, rounding

```
a = 1541
b = 1575
c = 1512
# I want to ratio the sum of these numbers to 128

total = a + b + c

rounded_a = round(a*128/total) # equals 43
rounded_b = round(b*128/total) # equals 44
rounded_c = round(c*128/total) # equals 42

total_of_rounded = rounded_a + rounded_b + rounded_c # equals 129 NOT 128

# I tried the floor

floor_a = math.floor(a*128/total) # equals 42
floor_b = math.floor(b*128/total) # equals 43
floor_c = math.floor(c*128/total) # equals 41

total_of_floor = floor_a + floor_b + floor_c # equals 126 NOT 128

# The exact values
# a: 42.62057044
# b: 43.56093345
# c: 41,81849611
```

The question is, how can I reach the total 128?

Note: I should stay at integer, not floating numbers.
Note 2: I can write a correction function which like adding +1 to total but it doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: So, your desired output is three integers a, b and c with sum 128 and with the exact same ratios as your original numbers? This seems impossible in general without a guarantee that a+b+c is divisible by 128. What should the output be with original numbers a=128, b=1, c = 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possibility: round `a` and `b` down, then add the missing parts to `c`.

```py
a = 1541
b = 1575
c = 1512
total = a + b + c  # 4628

ra = a * 128 // total
rb = b * 128 // total
rc = (c * 128 + (a * 128)%total + (b*128)%total) // total

print(ra,rb,rc)
# (42, 43, 43)
print(ra+rb+rc)
# 128
```

Comment: Thank you it seems work with this situation but can total exceed 128 with different values sometimes? Can I get 129 somehow?

Comment: @Rictrunks I am pretty convinced the total cannot exceed 128, but it's very hot this afternoon and I can't think straight right now.

Comment: I confirm that it never exceed 128. I've write a for loop with random values and it never exceed 128. Thank you again :)

Answer (score -1):

This is the way for it:

```
a = 1541
b = 1575
c = 1512
# I want to ratio the sum of these numbers to 128

total = a + b + c

total_of_round = round((a*128/total)+(b*128/total)+(c*128/total))
print (total_of_round)
```

Ouput:
`128`

Comment: you have float number but i don't give downvote

Comment: If he doesnt want a float number, then it's not possible with the provided values of `a`,`b` and `c` until all are divisible by 128. Not sure why and how did I get a downvote

Comment: here when you don't pay attention to OP's question you get downvote. OP says `Note: I should stay at integer, not floating numbers.` but I don't give downvote anybody at all